# incrementing variable inside loops

Tags: c

Im new to C language , been doing in it for hour but i found strange behavior of loop iterations
this code

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int c;
    int big;
    int small;
    while(c=getchar())
    {
        if(c>='A' && c<='Z');
        big++;
        printf("%d",big);
    }
    printf("end");
}
```

should increment int big whenever there is a upper case character. But it always print big numbers like 5452 and so on , did i miss something about iteration in c language or there is a bug in my simple code?

Comment: intialize big and try removing semicolon after if condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int big;
```

`big` is just declared not *intialized* , thus giving garbage value.

```
int big=0;     // also initialize small
```

Would work.

And

```
  if(c>='A' && c<='Z');
                      ^ will terminate if statement then and there
```

Due to `;` `big` will be incrementated even if the `if` condition is `false` .Remove `;` after `if`.

Answer (score 5):

You have junk semicolon and `big++` is executed regardless of `c>='A' && c<='Z'`.
You also have to initialize `big`.

Moreover, this code depends on the character code, so you should use `isupper` if it is not banned.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int c;
    int big = 0;
    int small;
    while(c=getchar()){ /* this loop should go infinitely in most case : compare with EOF to detect the end of input */
        if(isupper(c))
            big++;
        printf("%d",big); /* maybe you want to print newline after this */
    }
    printf("end");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: `isupper()` is better (more portable) since the chars 'A' to 'Z' is not guaranteed to be consecutive.

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialize `big` and the other variables to 0 in your case :

```
int c = 0;
int big = 0;
int small = 0;
```

Otherwise these variables will contain "random" values. This is a form of undefined behaviour that you will encounter a lot in C/C++.

Also these lines in your code are probably not doing what you expect

```
if(c>='A' && c<='Z');
    big++;
```

There is an empty statement at the end of the if. Remove the semicolon :

```
if(c>='A' && c<='Z')
    big++;
```

An extra problem is printing big in the while loop. `getchar()` will return any character you type including space. `printf("%d",big);` will be executed every time you type a character not every time you type an upper case or non white space char. So if you type "A A" you will get "112" There are a few ways to sort this. One solution :

```
if (!isspace(c)) {
    printf("%d", big);
}
```

Comment: thanks i realized it to o late , but althougt i initialized variables , it still outputs 11 insted of 1 22 instead of 2 and so on

Comment: I have added a possible explanation for this in my answer

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize variable big with 0.

```
int big = 0;
```

Comment: oops im retarded , but still it write doubled number e.g instead of 1 it writes 11 and so on

Comment: see last comment. you have to remove ; after "if" statement